# MR.Gestures ContentView on Tapped event has TapEventArgs.Touches null on iOS Simulator

Tags: xamarin.forms, ios-simulator, touch-event, mr.gestures

I have a control inherited from MR.Gestures.ContentView and subscribing to 
`Tapped += PinchToZoomContainer_Tapped` in constructor.
Also adding and image and some other control into `AbsoluteLayout` which being set to `Content`.

Inside of the even handler (on tapping), the `Touches` is `null` (not even mentioning it doesn't have touches in the list).

Also, having the following (if that might help):

```
e.Handled == true;
e.NumberOfTaps == 0;
e.Touches == null;
```

The issue appears only on `iOS` Simulator (Android is fine). (Currently cannot check live iOS device unfortunately).

So, don't have any idea why that might happen that Touches is null.

Comment: I just checked and the GestureSample works in the iPhone 11 simulator. Could you please file an issue on https://github.com/MichaelRumpler/GestureSample/issues and attach a sample project.

Comment: @MichaelRumpler, thanks for responding, but unfortunately I can't attach the project as it's a big existing project of some customer. The thing is that the ContentView contains Syncfusion Image Editor and the touches are processed in some complicated way. However, if you would say "oh, then this is not MR.Gestures issue then...", I would disagree with you as even if SF processes the gestures (transparently) some way as well, the MR.Gestures still invokes the `Touch` event and passes some data to it, which supposes to have any sense. (Especially considering it works well on Android).